# Accessing/modifying Ruby class attributes in Javascript/JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to access Ruby class attributes in a JS/JQ file.

Example:

```
class my_class
  attr_acessor :my_attr
end
```

In the Javascript, how can I access and modify this?

```
$('my_class').???
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ANSWER FOR UPDATED QUESTION**

You cannot modify a Ruby object from JavaScript.

**ANSWER FOR ORIGINAL QUESTION**

You need to [embed your Ruby code in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3597064/how-to-embed-ruby-in-javascript-rails-html-erb-file). Your js/html file must end in `js.erb` or `html.erb`.

Here is a quick example:

```
<script>
  var javascript_variable_attr = <%= @instance_of_my_class.my_attr %>
</script>
```

And FYI you cannot modify the Ruby object because you are not accessing the object in memory. Embedding Ruby will simply render the value into the js/html file. In other words, it is read only.

Comment: There is no templating engine, save for `erb`, huh?

Comment: There is `mustache` if you don't like `erb`. It's much cleaner. But at a low level it's basically the same thing. https://github.com/mustache/mustache